# HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal não funciona na classe Startup

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Estou tentando utilizar `HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;` em uma aplicação `web api 2` na classe `Startup` metodo `Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`.

A ideia é só subir um servidor `hangfire` se estiver em produção, não quero subir local.

O problema é que no servidor sempre vem `true`, e isso só acontece nessa classe, fiz uma rotina de teste em um `controller` e ele funcionou, retornou `false`.

Como eu poderia saber se é local ou não nesse momento do sistema?

Segue o código de exemplo:

```js
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
          
          
          
          bool isLocal = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal;
            if (isLocal == false) { 
                app.UseHangfireServer(boptions);
              
        }
          
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe Startup é executada quando o servidor sobe, e isso é feito pela propria maquina que o servidor está executando.

Por isso o IsLocal sempre vai retornar true...

[The IsLocal property returns true if the IP address of the request originator is 127.0.0.1 or if the IP address of the request is the same as the server's IP address.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx)